# Unable to switch between tabs of two different files

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have two separate `.java` files(classes), in one file I performed some actions and later by **clicking** a `link` a new tab is opened and continues in the second file and after performing some operations if I close that tab then no further action is performed on the previous tab and shows an error in `TestNG` console :

> nosuchelementfound

If I use a method to `switch` to previous `tab` it works but the second tab still remains which hides the actions happening on the first one.

I am running all three `java` files through one `.xml` file.

Kindly help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its simple before switching to the original tab (Parent tab) please close the other tab then switch to the original tab call

```
driver.close() // before switching note do not call driver.quit()
```